# Undefined Data When Calling From JSON in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a firebase URL to get some test data from as I'm still learning Ionic 2. Originally I had the error 'No HTTP Provider', but I fixed that by adding HttpModule to the app.module.ts file, but since that my data is always coming back as undefined.

The service is in it's own file (ww-api.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class WildWalkApi {

    private baseUrl = 'https://i2test-ea07c.firebaseio.com/';

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

    getLoginTest(){
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'login.json')
                .subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()));
        });
    }

}
```

Then this is exported using a shared file (shared.ts):

```
export * from './ww-api.service';
```

This then goes into app.componant.ts:

```
import { WildWalkApi } from './shared/shared';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [
    WildWalkApi,
    HttpModule
  ]
})
```

And finally I try and use the data in my view:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { WildWalkApi } from "../../app/shared/shared";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home-logged-in',
  templateUrl: 'home-logged-in.html',
})
export class HomeLoggedIn {

  private login;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private wwapi: WildWalkApi) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.wwapi.getLoginTest().then(data => this.login = data);
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad HomeLoggedIn ' + this.login);
  }

}
```

However this.login is always coming back as undefined.

Comment: http.get sends an AJAX request. The A in AJAX means Asynchronous. You can't expect the response to be available right after you've sent the request. That's why http.get returns an Observable<Response>, and not a Response. Also, adding HttpModule to the providers makes no sense.

Comment: I've output the data to the console in place of assigning it to the private variable and that works, so is it a case of I'm trying to show the variable before it's assigned?

Comment: Yes. You're trying to print the value right after sending the request, although it's only initialized long after, when the response comes back.

Comment: Is there a way for me to output this to the screen after the request is complete?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. Just use {{ login }} i your template, and when the login field is initialized, Angular will detect the change and display the login. But please learn how to use observables, because your way of transforming them to promises and ignoring error cases is counter-productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code You're trying to print the value right after sending the request but data is not available at that time .

You can use Event for it . Refer http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/

sample is here

---

In that file from where you want to use that event is 
 `this.events.publish('user:loggedIn', data);`

---

and that file where you want to show that data is

```
  this.events.subscribe('user:loggedIn', (data) => {
      console.log("page 1 data "+data);
      this.page1Message=data;
    });
```

This may work for you .